# How to get the RGB color values of a clicked pixel on a rendered image in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl2, pixel

In the same vein as [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47003/getting-an-images-rgb-value-at-click) and [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130484/fast-texture-pixel-access-using-sdl2), I recently ran into a problem in my C++/[SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) game architecture where I needed to get the R,G,B values from a clicked pixel in an image on the screen. That is, if the user clicked on a given image **surface** ([SDL_Surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface)) or **texture** ([SDL_Texture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Texture)), it would give you back the R,G,B values of the specific pixel in the image that you clicked. The specific use case was for a color picker, to allow users to customize UI elements with a clickable color palette.

This resulted in many hours of keyboard-bashing, because it turns out that SDL2 really, really is not built to have simple solutions to such problems when it comes to shaders and graphics architecture (and that's completely fine - it comes with the efficiency of the library).

Therefore, to save future game developers using C++/SDL2 the massive headache I had to endure, I'm posting the method I discovered below as a self-answer to this question. Hopefully it's helpful to someone with a similar problem in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much scouring the Internet, I discovered [this forum post](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/how-do-i-get-the-rgb-values-of-a-pixel-from-a-given-surface-and-x-and-y-coordinates-in-sdl2/26915/2), containing the following code that completely solved my problem. I've abridged it slightly for easy copy-paste into your project.

```
SDL_Color GetPixelColor(const SDL_Surface* pSurface, const int X, const int Y)
{
  // Bytes per pixel
  const Uint8 Bpp = pSurface->format->BytesPerPixel;

  /*
  Retrieve the address to a specific pixel
  pSurface->pixels  = an array containing the SDL_Surface' pixels
  pSurface->pitch       = the length of a row of pixels (in bytes)
  X and Y               = the offset on where on the image to retrieve the pixel; (0, 0) is the upper left corner
  */
  Uint8* pPixel = (Uint8*)pSurface->pixels + Y * pSurface->pitch + X * Bpp;

  Uint32 PixelData = *(Uint32*)pPixel;

  SDL_Color Color = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE};

  // Retrieve the RGB values of the specific pixel
  SDL_GetRGB(PixelData, pSurface->format, &Color.r, &Color.g, &Color.b);

  return Color;
}
```

All you need to do is provide:

- the **SDL_Surface** that was clicked into the function.
- the **X** and **Y** coordinates of the mouse click.

It will return the **SDL_Color** object of the pixel clicked - which can subsequently be broken up into R,G,B values if needed using the **.r** (red), **.g** (green), and **.b** (blue) properties.